# SSAS automation in c# - rename AAS attribute in c# pragmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, amo

I need help on SSAS automation in C#. I want to automate the rename the display name for the AAS attributes.
To automate the full process of renaming using c#. please help on this. kindly share any links or article on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS Documentation for AMO is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/amo/amo-concepts-and-object-model)

Add the [AMO nuget packge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64/) to your Visual Studio project

Then, you can connect to your SSAS Server from your code and change the dimension attribute.

E.g.,

```
    private static void UpdateAttribute()
    {
        var serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
        var databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
        var cubeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CubeName"];
        var dimensionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DimensionName"];
        var attributeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttributeName"];


        //Server
        var server = new Server();
        server.Connect(serverName);

        //Database
        var db = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);

        //Cube
        var cube = db.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);

        //dim
        var dim = db.Dimensions.FindByName(dimensionName);

        //attribute
        var attribute = dim.Attributes.FindByName(attributeName);

        var newAttributeName = $"{attribute.Name}_New";

        attribute.Name = newAttributeName;

        //this will update the dimension in the Server
        dim.Update();


    }
```

Result

The original attribute name was "Category" and now it is changed to "Category_New" in the Product dimension

[image]